# Get IPv4 address of specific Hyper-V VM

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, ipv4

I am trying to create a script that can turn on a specific Hyper-V VM then find out what IP Address it was assigned, and finally connect via RDP to it.

Not sure if this already exists...

So far I have the PS command to turn on the VM `Start-VM -Name MyVM` and it works.

To get the IP address of the VM the command `get-vm -Name MyVM| select -ExpandProperty networkadapters | select ipaddresses` works.

Not sure how to just get the IPv4 out of that command.

After this I would need to connect to RDP using a specific user.

I cannot connect the VM to the Internet, but just need the enough access to RDP and "print" to the Host PC. This is why I have it set as Internal in the Virtual Switch

Comment: Do you mean like: `(get-vm -Name MyVM).NetworkAdapters.IPAddresses`, or is it showing you multiple?

Comment: It shows the IPv4 and IPv6 adress.

Comment: Ahh, so something like this: `(get-vm -Name MyVM).NetworkAdapters.IPAddresses | ? { $_ -match '\.' }`?

Comment: That worked! I can save that to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

May be  (get-vm -Name MyVM).NetworkAdapters.IPAddresses[0] is simple

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34641199)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).